# Enable button after an item in ListBox is selected

Tags: javascript, asp.net

At the moment I'm using

```
<asp:ListBox ID="UserListBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="UserListBox_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
```

the button is disabled by default and after the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` is fired I am executing this behind.

```
protected void UserListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loginBtn.Enabled = true;
}
```

This is causing the site to reload. I don't want that, instead I need javascript but I'm not familiar.

Comment: in your page load make sure you check for page post back. If Not IsPostBack then load your list box.  This will prevent your list box from reloading every time you select an item

Answer (score 1):

A usefull way to solve it is use update panels:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ListBox ID="UserListBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="UserListBox_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
</ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

....

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ListBox ID="loginBtn" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="UserListBox_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UserListBox" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: That's very interesting but I already used javascript and did it!

Answer (score 1):

@Marco's answer is definitely more in-line with what you're looking for in the Web Forms world, but if you're set on using JavaScript start with:

```
document.getElementById("loginBtn").disabled = true;
```

This assumes that you've given your login button a fixed ID and ASP.NET isn't automatically assigning something crazy.

You'll have to remove the server-side event handler `UserListBox_SelectedIndexChanged` and replace it with a JavaScript event handler, otherwise the button will be disabled by JavaScript, but then the page will reload and undo the disable. If you had any other server-side code in that method it would need to find a new home, or you'd have to start really hacking at it.

Reasons like this are why it's nice to be able to stick with a single paradigm - do either server-side Web Forms work or client-side JavaScript. Avoid mixing & matching unless absolutely necessary - it's doable, but there will be tears and long nights.

Comment: So it's either `javascript` which is front-end or `updatepanel` which is server-side??

Comment: Generally, yes. Like I said, it is _possible_ to use both (I've gone that route before personally), but you have to be _constantly_ thinking about where is this code going to be executed (client or server) and the order in which things will happen. Even if the mixed solution works for now, the next time you need to put server-side code in your server-side event handler you'll be left having to refactor. I'd recommend the Update Panel route unless you have a compelling reason to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

*Solution using javascript:*

```
<script>
function checkSelect() {
    if (document.getElementById('<%=UserListBox.ClientID %>').value != '')
        document.getElementById('<%=loginBtn.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
}
</script>
```

just before `</asp:content>` also my list box now is:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="UserListBox" runat="server" onchange='checkSelect(this);'></asp:ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can simply use jquery to achieve the same, please consider below example

```
<div>
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Mango" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Banana" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Guava" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Pineapple" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Papaya" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Grapes" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:ListBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" Enabled="false"/>
        </div>
```

and register change event of select list in $(document).ready event of jquery like shown below

```
<script type="text/javascript">            
            $(document).ready(function () {                
                $('select[id*=ListBox1]').change( function () {
                    if($('select[id*=ListBox1] :selected').length >0)
                        $('#<%= btnLogin.ClientID%>').prop('disabled', false);
                    else
                        $('#<%= btnLogin.ClientID%>').prop('disabled', true);
                });
            });
        </script>
```

comment for any problem, Enjoy !!